# Changing the :checked style dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This code show the three buttons with check attribute.

I can change the color by clicking with :checked attribute in css.

However I want to change the color dynamically in javascript.

I can change the normal css by javascript but can I change :checked css???

```js
          
$li = $(`<li><input type="checkbox" name="issueCheck" id="1" 
                    value="1"><label for="1">1</label></li>`);
// I want to set the :checked background-color for this 'red'.
$('#issueCheckUl').append($li);   
         
$li = $(`<li><input type="checkbox" name="issueCheck" id="2" 
                   value="2"><label for="2">2</label></li>`);
 // I want to set the :checked background-color for this 'red'.
$('#issueCheckUl').append($li);
            

    
$li = $(`<li><input type="checkbox" name="issueCheck" id="3" 
                   value="3"><label for="3">3</label></li>`);   
 // I want to set the color here 'blue'' 
 $('#issueCheckUl').append($li);
```

```css
ul.ks-cboxtags {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li{
  display: inline;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li label{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
    border: 2px solid rgba(139, 139, 139, .3);
    color: #adadad;
    border-radius: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li label {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid #1bdbf8;
    background-color: #12bbd4; /* default color */
    color: #fff;
    transition: all .2s;
}

ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: absolute;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.ks-cboxtags li input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label {
  border: 2px solid #e9a1ff;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul class="ks-cboxtags" id="issueCheckUl"></ul>
```